# Как протестировать систему из N объектов, которые могут прибывать в 2х и более состояниях?

Tags: веб-программирование, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Всем привет. Вот в чем суть проблемы.

Как протестировать систему из N объектов, которые могут прибывать в 2х и более состояниях?

Чтобы было понятно, возьмем пример из жизни. У нас автомобиль, наша задача поехать, для этого упростим нашу модель до 3 объектов системы:

1. Ключ зажигания
2. Двигатель
3. Колеса
   Чтобы нам поехать, 3 этих элемента должны иметь статус активно. В нашел случае это 2^3 = 8 состояний, из них только 1 даёт нам положительный исход. В таком случае описать тест ручками из 8 состояний не составит труда, но если у нас в системе 10 элементов, то это уже 1024 состояния сами понимаете, что будет дальше.

Так и как нам тестироваться? Или быть может здесь должен быть совсем иной архитектурный подход?

п.с.
И вот к нам прибегает заказчик и кричит, что автомобиль не едет, в котором N элементов, скажите почему, мы делаем срез системы и.... что дальше?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В некоторых случаях помогут параметризованные тесты - есть такая фича в некоторых фреймворках. Можно автоматически перебрать эти 1024 состояния.

Comment: Все состояния разбивают на классы эквивалентности, т.е. такие подмножества, в которых состояния в некотором смысле эквивалентны с точки зрения сценария, который мы тестирует, а значит имеет смысл тестировать только одно состояние из класса. Пример, для тестирования сценария "при нажатии на педаль тормоза автомобиль замедляется" нет смысла рассматривать отдельно состояние элемента фары, который может быть вкл. или выкл. так что состояние фар можно не учитывать в начальных состояниях системы при тестировании этого сценария.